# How to find whether a string pattern exists in a python string?

Tags: python, string

Lets say  I have an arrays of strings.I want to find all the string which contain the following
substring , charachter digit digit digit charachter (CDDDC will be the pattern). For instance the format would be as following:
H554L
K007K

Is there any fast string expression matching to find such occurrences ?

Comment: Did you look into the regex module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: Seems like this might help me thanks !

Comment: Using the module `re`, you can have something like `pattern = re.compile('[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]')` and then test with something like `if pattern.match(your_string):`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things like this are the field of "regex". Regex is made for pattern matching. It of itself is a broad ttopic too much to explain here (check [regexbuddy or another site](https://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html)).

python has a regex compiler build in, under the `re` (as well as `regex` module). A simple solution would hence be:

```
word for word in somelist if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]\d{3}[a-zA-Z]", word)
```

Which iterates over somelist, and selects anything that matches (completely) a character in one of the two "ranges", followed by 3 digits, followed by a character in the range.

A noted as in the comments: `re.search` will match (find) any item which has a "part" of that item matching the "pattern". So it will match `a123b` as well as `abc b123cd`. If you wish to make sure that the full "word" in the array matches the substring use `re.fullmatch` instead.
Fullmatch will match `a123b` but not `abc b123cd` and not `ab123cd`

Comment: I'd rather suggest `re.search` instead of `re.match` - the OP mentioned "substring", which is not necessarily at the beginning of a string.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using `fullmatch` as I interpreted "substring" as "one sub of the array" - but your idea might be better. (and accidentally chose `match` as in javascript `match` does the same as fullmatch in python)

Comment: You don't need that `is not None` at the end of the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example with this regex:

**regex:** (?i)[A-Z]\d\d\d[A-Z]

```
import re
xx = ['aeeea','5eeae','H554L','juan','K007K']
for i in xx:
  r1 = re.findall(r"(?i)[A-Z]\d\d\d[A-Z]", i)
  print (', '.join(r1)
)
```

[Run the example online](https://repl.it/@Capriatto/re)